# mongoImport csv file accents are not detected

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I use mongoimport to import data stored in a csv file. Data has accents, like "è".
The command I run is the following:

`mongoimport -d mountain -c diary --type csv --file diary.csv --headerline`

when I check data with mongo shell, all the accents are replaced with a small square(I'm using windows command)

Consequently my angular application  doesn't recognise those symbols, also if encoding is set to "utf-8".

How to solve the issue?
Thanks

Comment: What is code page of imported file? You can check it notwpad++ for example.

Comment: you gave me the solution! the text was in ANSI. Converting it to utf-8  will let the import work. If you want to create an anwser I'll upvote and accept of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check input file codepage. You can do it by opening file in application like notepad.

`mongoimport` defaults to utf8